# How to make wifi widget in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, widget

I'm new to android development.

I have written an application that can turn WiFi On/Off.

Here is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.narun.wifi_control;
    import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
    import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.widget.ToggleButton;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Context context = getApplicationContext();
        final CharSequence wifioff = "Wifi is OFF";
        final CharSequence wifion = "Wifi is ON";
        final int duration= Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;


      final WifiManager wifiman=(WifiManager)     getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

        ConnectivityManager connman = (ConnectivityManager)     getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        boolean wifi =     connman.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();

       if(wifi){
        tb.setChecked(true);
        Toast toast= Toast.makeText(context, wifion, duration);

        toast.show();


       }
        else{
        tb.setChecked(false);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, wifioff, duration);
        toast.show();

        }


        tb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean     isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(isChecked){
                    wifiman.setWifiEnabled(true);
                    Toast toast= Toast.makeText(context, wifion, duration);
                    toast.show();
                }
                else{
                    wifiman.setWifiEnabled(false);
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, wifioff, duration);
                    toast.show();
                }

            }
        });



    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.narun.wifi_control.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:text="ToggleButton" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Wifi Control"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

and my manifest file

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.narun.wifi_control"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.narun.wifi_control.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

But I want to make it as a home screen widget as well that when we click, it should turn Wifi On/Off from home screen, how can I achieve this?

Comment: follow http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidWidgets/article.html

Comment: Thanks Kat-hat, i understand about the tutorial concept of widget, and other source from google, but what i want to do is to make a wifi widget from my existing application. None of the source i found was about making a widget of something else not about a system service related..